# small integral delimiter

Tags: symbols, delimiters

while reading a book on maths lately, I have seen a small integral delimiter such that, in what follows:

```
\begin{equation}
\sum_i^j A_{ij}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \cos x dx 
\end{equation}
```

the sum and integral would be of the same height. Are you aware of something like that?
Thank you

Comment: Are you fine with using smaller symbols for both the sum and the integral? Or you really want an integral as big as the usual sum?

Comment: yes, I want an integral sign as big as the usual sum

Comment: The size of the summation sign might differ depending on your math font. Do you mean the computer modern \sum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an up-to-date texlive-2010, if you use Asana Math font with `unicode-math` package (requires XeTeX or LuaTeX), you will get an integral that as high as the summation symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Asana-Math.otf}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\sum_i^j A_{ij}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \cos x dx 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

I'm not in front of a tex installation at the moment, but I think you're looking for

```
\smallint
```

Comment: Thanks but I think it is too small.

Answer (score 5):

`\int` is a "variable-sized symbol", so that it comes in two sizes: one for in-line formulas and one for display-formulas. The same is true for `\sum`; it just so happens that the text-style integral is almost the same height as the *display-style* sum symbol (in Lamport's *LaTeX User's Guide and Reference Manual*, both are about 4 mm tall, the display-style sum style a bit more, while the text-style sum symbol is only about 3 mm tall; the display-style integral, by contrast, is a bit more than 7 mm tall). So all you want is the integral sign to be displayed in text-mode, but only the integral sign (so the sum symbol is not changed in size).

One way to accomplish this is to define a macro `\smallint` as `\def\smallint{\begingroup\textstyle \int\endgroup}`. Upon testing it, it shows just a shade smaller than a displaystyle summation (if you put limits on the integral but not on the summation, they look about the same); if you have limits on the sum and the integral, then both done in `\textstyle` looks better, but then you need to use the `\limits` command after `\sum` so that the limits occur above and below the sigma, instead of right after. Thus, if you have limits on the summation, I would suggest

```
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i}^j A_{ij}\begingroup\int\endgroup_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\cos x\,dx
\end{equation}
```

or

```
\begin{equation}
\mathop{\textstyle\sum}\limits_i^j 
   A_{ij}\begingroup\textstyle\int\endgroup_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\cos x\,dx
\end{equation}
```

(or using a macro for the small integral sign). (Note by the way the thin space before the `dx` in the integral).

Comment: This isn't quite right. You need to use `\begingroup\textstyle\int\endgroup` and not `{\textstyle\int}`. It is less obvious with `\sum`.

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference is; I thought `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` just amount to the same thing as localizing things by the use of curly brackets.

Comment: PS How do you get the multiline display to show in the page?

Comment: In many cases they are the same, but not always. In math mode, braces introduce a new subformula whereas `\begingroup ... \endgroup` is just a new group. If you compare the outputs of the two, the difference should be clear. The lower limit for the integral is too far to the right if you use `{...}`. Of course, you may want them to line up vertically even though there is extra space. In that case, braces work nicely.

Comment: Ah; thanks. I also see now how to get the multiline display.

Comment: I guess that a good rule of thumb is if you want a group, use `\begingroup`/`\endgroup`, even if you think it's likely to be identical to braces.

Comment: Doing this changes the size of _all integrals after the first_ `\smallint`. E.g. `\int x dx + \smallint y dx + \int z dz` will turn into one regular and two small integral signs.

Answer (score 4):

```
\begin{equation}
\textstyle \sum_i^j A_{ij}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \cos x dx 
\end{equation}
```

Comment: thanks, that could be something like this. But I was also thinking on a specific font offering this small integral delimiter.